# Как конвертировать цвет пикселя ABGR в ARGB?

Tags: c++, gdi

```
ARGB getPixelColor(HWND hWnd, int x, int y)
{
    HDC dc = GetDC(hWnd);
    ARGB color = GetPixel(dc, x, y);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, dc);
    return color;
}
```

использую эту функцию получаю значение ABGR например 0x000248ac но мне нужно ARGB 0x00ac4802 подскажите как мне "инвертировать" это значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uint32_t ABGR_to_ARGB(uint32_t abgr)
{
  uint32_t tmp = ((abgr >> 16) ^ abgr) & 0xFF;
  return abgr ^ ((tmp << 16) | tmp);
}
```

Другой вариант (ссылаясь на ответ от @Maxim Egorushkin [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51516082/187690))

```
uint32_t ABGR_to_ARGB(uint32_t abgr) 
{
  uint32_t grab = abgr >> 16 | abgr << 16;
  return (abgr & 0xFF0FF00) | (grab & 0x00FF00FF);
}
```

Если ваш компилятор достаточно умен для того, чтобы сообразить, что `abgr >> 16 | abgr << 16` - это ни что иное как циклический сдвиг `abgr` на 16, то этот вариант странслируется в очень компактный машинный код на платформах с инструкцией циклического сдвига.

Answer (score 4):

```
unsigned int ABRGtoARGB(unsigned int rgba)
{
    return (rgba & 0x00FF0000) >> 16 | (rgba & 0x0000FF00) | (rgba & 0x000000FF) << 16;
}
```

разобрался

Comment: А альфа-канал за что выброшен оказался?

Comment: в данном случае он мне не нужен был, мне в идеале нужно было rgb

Comment: В вопросе написано "мне нужно ARGB". В ответе написано "мне нужно было rgb". Этот ответ не является ответом на вопрос.